# Review paper on particle filter

Tags: particle-filter, references

I have found online a draft of an excellent review [paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2142010114651707902&hl=en&as_sdt=0,9&sciodt=0,9) by Zhe Chen entitled "Bayesian Filtering: From Kalman Filters to Particle Filters, and Beyond". According to Google Scholar, the citation for the published version is "Statistics 182 (1), 1-69, 2003" but the journal I find with that name (ISSN: 0233-1888) does not have the paper; in fact, volume numbers for 2003 are nowhere near 182. How can I find the correct journal name, and preferably ISSN and DOI for this paper, or determine that it was not ever published?

Comment: I found a DOI on Zhe Chen's ResearchGate profile (10.1080/02331880309257) but it doesn't resolve to anything. DOIs are supposed to be opaque, but it does *look* like the other DOIs from *Statistics* circa 2003. Weird, eh?

Comment: @MattKrause That DOI resolves to "CAPABILITY MEASURES FOR m -DEPENDENT STATIONARY PROCESSES
Source:  Statistics [0233-1888] CHEN yr:2003 vol:37 iss:1 pg:1 -24" which is not the paper I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a dissertation thesis or something close to that, not published in a scholarly journal but by Hamilton University, as clarified in ref. 2 of [Feng et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705811015943).

Comment: A tantalizing clue! Unfortunately, I don't think it's correct. A search of the McMaster U. catalog (Hamilton is the name of the city) shows that Zhe Chen's [thesis](http://catalogue.mcmaster.ca/catalogue/Record/1258613) has a different title. However, it does show who Zhe Chen's advisor was, so that might be a way to get more information. Also, that reference by Feng looks interesting in its own right.